# View of custom class

Tags: objective-c

I have the following class:

```
@interface Gamer {
...
}

+(id) CreatePlayer;
@end

@implementation Gamer

+(id) CreatePlayer
{
  return [[[self alloc] init]autorelease];
}
@end
```

I need to use the Gamer in an another class as instance variable.
For example like this:

```
@interface Layer{
  Gamer * mCenterGamer;
}
@end
@implementation
-(void) init{
   mCenterGamer =  [Gamer CreatePlayer];
}
-(void) exampleFuncForUseGamer{
   [mCenterGamer ...]// some methods of the Gamer class
}
@end
```

Is it correct? (I think autorelease freed the mCenterGamer after exiting from the init function)

Comment: Sorry, only a comment, not an answer: You are not using the standard Cocoa pattern for allocating a new object. Unless you have a good reason (any you might), you should stick to the standard pattern — `mCenterGamer = [[Gamer alloc] init];` and use the `init` method of `Gamer` to prepare it for use

Answer (score 0):

You need to retain mCenterGamer (and make sure to release it in the Layer's `-dealloc` method). Also, `-init` needs `id` as its return type:

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init])
       mCenterGamer = [[Gamer CreatePlayer] retain];

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [mCenterGamer release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Your `-exampleFuncForUseGamer` should be fine, depending on what you're trying to do there.